# Adding SSL Certificate to EC2 instances via Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssl, ssl-certificate

I purchased an SSL certificate and have successfully uploaded it to my AWS Elastic Load Balancer.

When I visit my website, www.obystudio.com, it still doesn't show the "https://". Do I need to do more? If so, can someone please guide me in the proper direction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to open up your security group to port 443 as well. In case you're not familiar with how to do that you can do this in the AWS Console by:

1. Selecting your ELB in the Load Balancers section
2. Selecting the Security tab
3. Click on the security group shown there
4. Select the Inbound tab
5. Click edit
6. Click Add Rule
7. Select https from the dropdown and ensure the source is set to 0.0.0.0/0 (anywhere)

After you've done this and saved, you should be able to reach your site over https.

Comment: These are all true but I wonder if OP expects the page to switch to https just because the ELB is equipped for it and has overlooked the need for the back-end servers to send a `301` redirect on unencrypted requests to actually switch the browser over.

Comment: Fair point, but as the https version of the site isn't resolving I figured that was the part the OP wanted fixed